# How to store value in a map inside map?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a section of code like this:

```
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int[] time : times) {
        if (!hashMap.containsKey(time[0])) {
            hashMap.put(time[0], new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
        }
        hashMap.get(time[0]).put(time[1], time[2]);
    }
```

Inside this code, `time` is an array with 3 elements (e.g [0, 1, 2]), and `times` is made up of such array. I first stored elements like this but when I access the map later, it throws a `NullPointerException`. Does it mean that the map actually stores nothing?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Please show the code where you access `hashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. After you run it, if `time[]` is `{ 0, 1, 2 }`, I would expect

```
System.out.println(hashMap.get(0).get(1))
```

would output "2".

Check your code for accessing the map.

Note that if you try with a different top-level key, e.g.

```
int x = hashMap.get(3).get(4);
```

you would get a NullPointerException , since `hashMap.get(3)` returns null